# How to convert an object into a JTable in Java

Tags: java, swing, csv, jtable

I recently started using OpenCSV's CSVReader to get data from a CSV file to a JTable in java, but I keep getting an error. DaTroop gave the answer to how to get data from the CSV here: [import csv to JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466079/import-csv-to-jtable) . In my case I copied the code

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv")); 
List myEntries = reader.readAll();
JTable table = new JTable(myEntries.toArray());
```

into Netbeans IDE 7.4, but I keep getting the error "Incompatible types - Object Cannot be converted to TableModel". in the

```
(myEntries.toArray());
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

As in comment, please find my whole code snippet. The JFrame works and views, so it should be called fine.

```
public static void LoadLog() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        LogViewer log = new LogViewer();
        log.setVisible(true);
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("testog.csv")); 

String[][] rowData = {
    { "A", "B" },
    { "C", "D" }
};

List<String[]> myEntries = reader.readAll();
rowData = myEntries.toArray(new String[0][]);

String[] columnNames = { "Column 1", "Column 2" };

System.out.println(myEntries);

table1 = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);

log.pack();
log.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that `reader.readAll()` returns `List<String[]>`.

Also note that calling `myEntries.toArray()` returns `Object[]`, and not `Object[][]`, or more specifically `String[][]`,  which would be more preferable to work with.

The closest constructor for JTable that matches what you're trying to do would be this one:

```
JTable(Object[][] rowData, Object[] columnNames)
```

So you need to supply both `rowData` and `columnNames`. You can get the `rowData` like this:

```
List<String[]> myEntries = reader.readAll();
String[][] rowData = myEntries.toArray(new String[0][]);
```

Create a variable to hold the column names (or don't, your choice, but column names are still required):

```
String[] columnNames = { "Column 1", "Column 2" };
```

And then create your JTable:

```
JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
```

---

Based on your comment, here's a short and simple code snippet for creating and displaying a table. As long as you initialize `rowData` and `columnNames` with the correct data, then it should work fine.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

String[][] rowData = {
    { "A", "B" },
    { "C", "D" }
};
String[] columnNames = { "Column 1", "Column 2" };
JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));

frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Is there any further code to add to construct the table? This is my final code and when using System.out.pritln, I am getting data out, but I am not seeing any data in my table?

Comment: I've added an example of how to create and show a table. If you can't get your program to work after making any necessary modifications, then you may need to show us more of your code.

Comment: Where in your code do you add `table1` to your `log`/JFrame?

Comment: It is added using a Pallete in Netbeans. The table variable is renamed using the properties. Could you maybe provide a way to add it to the frame without adding it using the palette adder in Netbeans?

Comment: Using your code I realised that I'm not setting a model table. Thanks for your help!