# How to create JTable that is initially empty and then fill it out with the data from CSV file?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to create JTable that is initially empty. Then a user may load data from CSV file. So, it means that the number of rows in `rowData` is not known apriori. How should I change this line `Object rowData[][] = new Object[][]{};` to fit my goal?

```
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

class PaxListTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

  Object rowData[][] = new Object[][]{};

  String columnNames[] = Constants.columnNamesPax;

  public int getColumnCount() {
    return columnNames.length;
  }

  public String getColumnName(int column) {
    return columnNames[column];
  }

  public int getRowCount() {
    return rowData.length;
  }

  public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
    return rowData[row][column];
  }

  public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
    return (getValueAt(0, column).getClass());
  }

  public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column) {
    rowData[row][column] = value;
  }

  public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
    return (column != 10);
  }
}
```

Comment: Does OpenCSV fill your needs? [Import CSV to JTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466079/import-csv-to-jtable) & [OpenCSV project](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Arrays are a poor choice for this; use `List`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13919878/230513).

Comment: @trashgod: In this case where do I populate the table model with the data from CSV?

Comment: @Alexander Ortiz: I already do this, but the question is how to put all things together: CSV reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("MyList.csv"));
              List<String[]> allUsers = reader.readAll();
              tableUsersModel.setRowCount(0);
              for (String[] obj: allUsers)
               tableUsersModel.insertRow(tableUsers.getRowCount(),obj);

Comment: Given a `List<Row>` of parsed data, you don't have to, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17384208/230513).