# Which Is the correct way of create a table that show data from text file without SQL, MySQL and JTable?

Tags: mysql, sql, groovy, jtable

I'm trying to create a table like SQL style with AWT but this method only can show 1000 files of data. How I could show a large data of 4000 to 10000 lines in CSV?

This is an example of code that I tried without good performance:

```
def MH=  new File('vengggfdus2xvhg.csv').getText('UTF-8').split("\n").size()*12
def ML= new File('vengggfdus2xvhg.csv').getText('UTF-8').split("\n")[2].split(";").size() *140
def scale=MH*ML

  image3 = new BufferedImage(ML,MH, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    fgImage= ImageIO.read(new File("raya5.png"));
    fgImagev= ImageIO.read(new File("rayav5.png"));
      g = image3.getGraphics();
        g.setFont(g.getFont().deriveFont(12f));
    def xyh=0
    def xyh1=20
    String valz=""
    String valp=""

    stringInput= new File('vengggfdus2xvhg.csv').getText('UTF-8').replaceAll(/(.+\n)/){ xyh=0 ;g.drawImage(fgImagev, xyh+0,xyh1+20, null);valz="hh"  ;it[1].replaceAll(/([^;]+);/){ valp=it[1].replaceAll(/(.{22}).+/, '$1');g.drawString("${valp}", xyh,xyh1); g.setColor(Color.BLUE); g.drawImage(fgImage, xyh+0,xyh1-20, null);  xyh =xyh+140; valz}             ; xyh1=xyh1+18  ;        }

     println "scale"

    print "hiji2"
    g.dispose();   
    print "hiji"
      ImageIO.write(image3, "png", new File("pokemon1.png"));
```

Comment: *"Im trying to create a table like sql style with awt.."* Why use AWT?

Comment: because I can draw with graphics

Comment: I only trying to show the data in gui

Comment: I draw using  g.drawImage

Comment: awt work well with 2000 lines

Comment: but for  3000 or more works very bad

Comment: OK.. I should have asked: Why **not** use Swing & `JTable` to render the data? If you ultimately need a `BufferedImage`, it is possible to get one from a `JTable`.

Comment: Are you drawing a CSV line by line? Use a JTable or a javafx tableview... Don't do what your doing, it's just a little crazy

Comment: ok I will try the jtable thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466079/import-csv-to-jtable